# How to customise the css fields of an alert box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My requirement is to customize the alert box with css attributes. Currently I am achieving something similar to that through the following code:

JQUERY:

```
$('<div class="alertMessage">Error first</div>')
.insertAfter($('#componentName'))
.fadeIn('fast')
.animate({opacity: 1.0}, 2200)
.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

CSS:

```css
.alertMessage {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: .5em;

    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left top, 0, left top, 1012, color-stop(0, #F07E1A), color-stop(1, #F58CCB));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at left top, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);

    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid white;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: none;
 }
```

The above code will fadeIn and fadeOut after few seconds. Also the fade in and fade out will happen next to the component which I would have mentioned in code as

```
insertAfter($('#componentName'))
```

My requirement is:

1. The alert message should come in the center of the window. Just like the normal alert box
2. The alert message should have an Okay button. Just like the normal alert box.

Will I be able to achieve this only by adding Okay button to the div and adding a behavior for the Okay button. Or is there any way to extend the generic alert box behaviour and customize it with the css properties which I have mentioned above? If Yes, How to achieve it?

Comment: No, you can not modify the look of the "native" alert message box with CSS, because that is not even HTML. Maybe you want to have a look at _jQuery UI Dialog_? http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: he never mentioned to modify the built in alert message, did he?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement the appearance and behaviour yourself, the standard alert box is not customizable.

An alternative as your already using jQuery is to use the functionality provided by [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use JQuery Dialog, Please look the following link
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Answer (score 0):

you can try this with your own code. You don't need any blugins. Check my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ponrajpaul/tNgkz/

**HTML**

```
<div class="alertMessage">
  alert message
  <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.alertMessage{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, left top, 0, left top, 1012, color-stop(0, #F07E1A), color-stop(1, #F58CCB));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(left top, circle farthest-corner, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at left top, #F07E1A 0%, #F58CCB 100%);
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid white;
  }
```

**SCRIPT**
script for position center to the message div

```
jQuery.fn.posCenter = function () {
    this.css("position","fixed");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

script for call the alert message div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.alertMessage').posCenter();
});
```

whenever you want to display alert message just call this function. Before set **display:none** to alert message.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.alertMessage').css({"display" : "block"});
  $('.alertMessage').posCenter();  
  $('input.ok').click(function(){
     $('.alertMessage').css({"display" : "none"});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default popups like alert,confirm are not customizable...u need to make your own div with

CSS

`#yourPopupDiv {position : absolute`}

and add this CSS using jquery(or javascript)

```
$('#yourPopupDiv').css('top', $('body').height()/2 - $('#yourPopupDiv').height()/2);
$('#yourPopupDiv').css('left', $('body').width()/2 - $('#yourPopupDiv').width()/2);
```

or use [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) which does all these..